# Map Array to Hash Syntax error

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, dictionary

I'm not too sure why, but I keep getting a syntax error with the following: `near ") :"`

```
my %temp =  map { /(\S+)\:x\:(\S+)\:(\S+)/ ? ($1 => $2) : (); 
                  ($1.'members' => $3) : ()
                } @output;
```

Ideally what I want to do, is assign `$1 to $2`, and then `$1.'members'` to $3. It seems ok to me, but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the `map` for a moment, and just look at this code:

```
/(\S+)\:x\:(\S+)\:(\S+)/ ? ($1 => $2) : (); 
($1.'members' => $3) : ();
```

What's that supposed to mean? This line in particular is a syntax error:

```
($1.'members' => $3) : ();
```

I think you want:

```
/(\S+)\:x\:(\S+)\:(\S+)/
   ? ($1 => $2, $1.'members' => $3)
   : ();
```

Adding back in the `map`:

```
my %temp = map {
               /(\S+)\:x\:(\S+)\:(\S+)/
                   ? ($1 => $2, $1.'members' => $3)
                   : ();
           } @output;
```